# Cannot connect from external PC to Java application running in Docker container - Linux

Tags: java, linux, docker

I have a Java server application running in Docker Container. The container runs in a Linux server (Ubuntu 18.04 LTS), with a static IP address. Another Java application, running in a PC, has to connect to the Java server application.

The server app listens for TCP connection requests and the PC App can open a TCP connection, knowing port and static IP address of Server App.

Let me say that the app server listens on port 5000 for TCP connection requests; then, when a TCP connection arrives from external, the TCP server releases a connection assigning a port in the range 5000-20000. So first question is if this range 5000-20000 to be exposed?

Before, the Java server application runned in a linux server, without container, and it worked.

Now, with the Server App inside the Docker container, the connection is refused; I guess that there is a problem of ports.

The Java application is configured by a dockerfile like that:

```
FROM openjdk:8-oraclelinux8
WORKDIR /mydir
# VOLUME . /
COPY ["./My_name_Java_app.jar", "./My_name_Java_app.properties", "./"]
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 8080
EXPOSE 5000-20000
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/java", "-Djava.awt.headless=true", "-jar", "My_name_Java_app.jar"]
```

I have read that I have to publish the ports on Docker run command, but when I run the container by:

```
docker run -d --name my_container -p 5000-20000:5000-20000/tcp -p 80:80 -p 8080:8080 -v /root/my_app/volume:/mydir my_image
```

I get the following error (in Linux terminal - note that the final full stop is exactly whay I get):

```
linux docker: Error response from daemon xxxxxxxxx: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint Error starting userland proxy:.
```

So finally my target is that the PC app can connect to Server app using the port 5000 and opening a connection in the range of port (5001-20000).

I also exposed ports 80 and 8080 because the Server App must perform some http requests to a website, so I suppose that I have to expose the ports 80 and 8080; other question is if do I have also to expose and publish 80 and 8080 by -p option?

By the way, if I delete (see below) the -p option with 80 and 8080, I get always the same error.

```
docker run -d --name my_container -p 5000-20000:5000-20000/tcp -v /root/my_app/volume:/mydir my_image
```

Moreover, if I eliminate at all the -p option, the container starts without errors.

Comment: You are opening a privileged port (`80`) on the host. I would assume that this (in one form or another) causes the problem. Can you try to change `-p 80:80` to `-p 9080:80`?

Comment: Hi, I'll try,again, but I already tried also omitting -p 80:80 and -p 8080:8080, leaving only  -p 1000-2000:1000-2000/tcp. But I get always the error

Comment: Hm true. all ports `< 1024` are privileged... so... can you try replacing `-p 1000-2000:1000-2000/tcp` with `-p 11000-12000:1000-2000/tcp` as well?

Comment: You only need the `EXPOSE` and `docker run -p` options if your container accepts incoming connections.  So if your server listens on port 9000 you should mention that, but you don't need to mention ports on other servers you connect to.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED:
AT the end of the story nothing was really wrong, simply I had to expose (inside the dockerfile) and publish with -p option (in docker run command) only the only port that I really need (that is the 5000), and not the big range of ports I considered at beginning.